# Partizip II von "unterhalten" = "unterGEhalten"?

Tags: past-participle, inflection

The word "unterhalten" (in the sense of "to entertain / sustain / chat with sb.") is a verb with a non-separable prefix:

> "Ich unterhalte mich"
>   **NOT:** <s>"Ich halte mich unter."</s>

Typically, these verbs form their Partizip II without the -ge- affix:

> "Ich habe mich unterhalten."

Nevertheless, [the Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterhalten_betreiben_versorgen) lists "unter**ge**halten" as a legitimate Partizip II. I wonder how this can be true, and in which regions of the German-speaking world people would say:

> "Ich habe mich mit ihm untergehalten."

Comment: I think "unter**ge**halten" is only possible for the meaning 2b: "etwas halten" (hold in the hand) in the meaning of *to hold sth. under sth."

Comment: "unterhalten" in the sense of "to hold sth. under sth." is out of the question here; that is a different verb, and not the one the Duden entry links to. The Duden entry I referenced specifically refers to "unterhalten" in the sense of "entertain", "sustain" (which is your 2b) or "chat", and it lists "unterGEhalten" as its Partizip II.

Comment: Except that the Duden entry for the other verb also lists both participle forms, even though in that case "unterhalten" is clearly wrong. I think that's just a bug — merging the participle forms of different entries.

Comment: @ParaDice You are right, but as Takkat said in his answer, too, "untergehalten" is only possible for this meaning. I think Em1 is right, that this is just an error in the Duden website.

Comment: Ich habe diesen Fehler gerade via Kontaktformular beim Duden gemeldet und um Beispiele für die ungewöhnlichen Wortformen gebeten. Mal sehen, wie sie reagieren.

Comment: Die Duden-Redaktion hat mir geantwortet, aber nicht zufriedenstellend. Die Duden-Webseite suggeriert weiterhin, wir hätten uns unter*ge*halten.

Comment: @Roland Illig: Danke für's Dranbleiben und das Update. Dann wollen sie's eben nicht anders. Für Fremdsprachenlerner dennoch weiterhin irreführend.

Answer (score 10):

#### [unterhalten](https://www.dwds.de/wb/unterhalten)

These are two different verbs with different meaning but same spelling (see link to the DWDS dictionary)

1. Only the more common meaning *to entertain, chat* is non-separable and hence does not have the **ge-** prefix on inflection.
2. The other meaning *to hold sth. under sth.* is separable and inflected to *untergehalten*.

For all inflections also see: [unterhalten (1)](http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?input=unterhalten&features=(Cat%20V)(Aux%20haben)(Pref%20No-Detach)&dispatch=inflection&lang=en) and [unterhalten (2)](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/unterhalten:V:haben:Detach). The (identical) entries you had found from Duden online  ([1](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterhalten_betreiben_versorgen),[2](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterhalten_darunterhalten)) are wrong.

Comment: "unterhalten" in the sense of "to hold sth. under sth." is out of the question here; as you say, it is a different verb, and not the one the Duden entry links to. The Duden entry I referenced specifically refers to "unterhalten" in the sense of "entertain", "sustain" (which is your 2b) or "chat", and it lists "unterGEhalten" as its Partizip II.

Comment: Never trust Duden if you have other resources... no just joking but if you look at the other meaning of [unterhalten](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterhalten_darunterhalten) you find the identical table. I would say this is wrong there because we would not say *"Am Brunnen habe ich meine Hände unterhalten, damit sie nass werden"*.

Comment: Yeah, I think ParaDice just found a bug in Duden online. Duden has separate entries for both verbs but they confuse the participle forms.

Comment: If only Duden would give away free copies of their books to people who trace their bugs...

Comment: ... but you need to be quick spotting them. Because whatever is in the Duden becomes common pratice over time. (Or was it the other way round?)

Answer (score 2):

[Takkats answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38071/1487) is correct. I just want to add some examples, to make it clearer.  The Verb »unterhalten« has many meanings. It is not separable in most of them. But there also exists a meaning (#6 in my list) where it is a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb). If it is separable, and if you have to use *Partizip II*, then there will be a ***-ge-*** between the two parts.

In the following examples I use:

- **Gegenwart (Präsens)**
  **separable verbs are split in two words**
  This corresponds in most cases to *simple present tense* in English. In German you have to split separable verbs into its parts. The former second part has to stand on position 2 and is inflected together with the subject (number and person), while the former first part moves to the end of the sentence and is not inflected.

  > Ich **mache** die Tür **auf.** = I open the door.
  >   Du **machst** die Tür **auf.** = You open the door.
  >   Wir **machen** die Tür **auf.** = We open the door.
- **Zukunft (Futur 1)**
  **the verb is used in its dictionary form (infinitive)**
  In most cases this corresponds to *simple future tense*. In German you have to use a form of *werden* as auxiliary verb at position 2, which has to inflected with the subject. But the main verb will be used in its connected form, and as infinitive. This infinitive sometimes is also called the »dictionary form«, because it is the basic form of a verb which is listed in a dictionary.

  > Ich **werde** die Tür **aufmachen.** = I will open the door.
  >   Du **wirst** die Tür **aufmachen.** = You will open the door.
  >   Wir **werden** die Tür **aufmachen.** = We will open the door.
- **Vergangenheit (Perfekt)**
  **past participle is needed**
  This German tense can correspond to different forms of past tense in English. Here, in my examples, I always use *simple past tense*. In German this tense is build with a form of *haben* or *sein* as auxiliary verb at position 2, and again it's this auxiliary verb that is inflected. The full verb again stands at the end of the sentence in a compound form, but it is not infinitive. It is »Partizip Perfekt« or »Partizip II« (*past participle*). And the rule for all separable verbs is: squeeze the syllable ***-ge-*** between the two parts:

  > Ich **habe** die Tür **auf*ge*macht.** = I opened the door.
  >   Du **hast** die Tür **auf*ge*macht.** = You opened the door.
  >   Wir **haben** die Tür **auf*ge*macht.** = We opened the door.

---

### 1. jemanden unterhalten = to entertain somebody

not separable

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Der Künstler **unterhält** das Publikum.
  >   The artist entertains the audience.
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > Der Künstler wird das Publikum **unterhalten**.
  >   The artist will entertain the audience.
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > Der Künstler hat das Publikum **unterhalten**.
  >   The artist entertained the audience.

### 2. sich unterhalten = to be amused

not separable

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Barbara besucht ein Kabarett und **unterhält** sich prächtig.
  >   Barbara visits a comedy show and is very amused.
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > Barbara wird ein Kabarett besuchen und wird sich prächtig **unterhalten**.
  >   Barbara will visit a comedy show and will be very amused.
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > Barbara hat ein Kabarett besucht und hat sich prächtig **unterhalten**.
  >   Barbara visited a comedy show and was very amused.

### 3. sich mit jemanden unterhalten = to talk with somebody

not separable

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Walter **unterhält** sich mit Michael.
  >   Walter talks with Michael.
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > Walter wird sich mit Michael **unterhalten**.
  >   Walter will talk with Michael.
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > Walter hat sich mit Michael **unterhalten**.
  >   Walter talked with Michael.

### 4. jemanden unterhalten = to support somebody (with money)

not separable

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Herr Steiner **unterhält** drei Geliebte.
  >   Mr. Steiner has three lovers (and supports them with money).
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > Herr Steiner wird drei Geliebte **unterhalten**.
  >   Mr. Steiner will have three lovers ...
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > Herr Steiner hat drei Geliebte **unterhalten**.
  >   Mr. Steiner had three lovers ...

### 5. etwas (eine Beziehung) unterhalten = to maintain (a relationship)

not separable

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Der Präsident **unterhält** Beziehungen zu Russland.
  >   The president maintains connections to Russia.
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > Der Präsident wird Beziehungen zu Russland unterhalten.
  >   The president will maintain connections to Russia.
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > Der Präsident hat Beziehungen zu Russland unterhalten.
  >   The president maintained connections to Russia.

### 6. etwas unterhalten = to hold something under

This one is separable!

- Gegenwart (Präsens)

  > Das Gerät hat ein Leck! Du **hältst** eine Tasse **unter**.
  >   The device has a leak. You hold a cup under it.
- Zukunft (Futur 1)

  > ... Du wirst eine Tasse **unterhalten**.
  >   ... You will hold a cup under it.
- Vergangenheit (Perfekt)

  > ... Du hast eine Tasse **untergehalten**.
  >   ... You held a cup under it.