# Präposition + trennbares Verb

Tags: preposition, separable-verb

Während ich eine [andere Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/38070/1487) beantwortete, fiel mir auf, dass mir bei der Verwendung des Verbs *unterhalten* etwas nicht ganz klar ist. Dabei geht es um jene Bedeutung des Verbs, die im folgenden Beispiel verwendet wird:

> Es tropfte aus der Kaffeemaschine, als ich sie von der Küche in den Übersiedelungs-LKW trug. Ich konnte aber keine Tasse **unterhalten**, weil ich keine Hand frei hatte.

Den Teil, in dem  *»unterhalten«* vorkommt, kann man nun variieren:

Wenn ich nicht von der Möglichkeit einer Tätigkeit, sondern von der Tätigkeit selbst spreche, brauche ich das Partizip Perfekt (um das es übrigens in der oben verlinkten Frage ging):

> Ich habe keine Tasse **untergehalten**.

Wenn ich doch eine Hand frei gehabt hätte (nur um die Verneinung loszuwerden):

> Ich habe eine Tasse **untergehalten**.

Wenn ich zusätzlich noch angebe, worunter ich die Tasse gehalten habe:

> 1. Ich habe eine Tasse *unter* die Kaffeemaschine **untergehalten**.

Natürlich kann man hier auch ein anderes Verb verwenden:

> 2. Ich habe eine Tasse *unter* die Kaffeemaschine **gehalten**.

Aber das ist, zumindest in der Vergangenheit, nicht zwingend erforderlich. Der Satz (1) ist völlig korrekt und verständlich. Aber wie ist das in der Gegenwart, wenn das trennbare Verb tatsächlich getrennt wird:

> 3. Ich **halte** eine Tasse *unter* die Kaffeemaschine **unter**.
> 4. Ich **halte** eine Tasse *unter* die Kaffeemaschine.

(3) ist aus (1) entstanden. In (3) erscheint das Wort *unter* zweimal. Das erste Mal als Präposition, die Teil eines Präpositionalobjekts ist (*»unter die Kaffeemaschine«*), und das zweite Mal als Kern eines trennbaren Verbs am Ende des Satzes.

(4) ist aus (2) entstanden. In (4) wird anstelle des trennbaren Verbs *unterhalten* das nicht trennbare Verb *halten* verwendet, wodurch *unter* nur einmal, nämlich als Präposition, im Satz steht.

Das Problem, das ich sehe, ist, dass (3) und (4) eigentlich genau dasselbe aussagen. Man könnte (3) also bis zum Wort *Kaffeemaschine* wie (4) lesen und verstehen, und stolpert dann über das anscheinend überflüssige zweite  *unter* am Ende.

Meine Frage lautet nun:

- **Ist der Satz (3) richtig und stilistisch einwandfrei?** (Bitte mit Begründung)

---

Dass die Präposition eines Präpositionalobjekts mit dem Präfix eines trennbaren Verbs übereinstimmt, kommt des Öfteren mal vor. Aber nur in bestimmten Fällen entsteht daraus ein Konflikt. **Warum?**

Zur Veranschaulichung drei Beispiele:

<sub>Erika möchte ihr Fernrohr auf einem kleinem Stativ montieren:</sub>

> Erika hat ein Stativ *aufgebaut.*
>   Erika hat ein Stativ *auf* dem Tisch *aufgebaut.*
>   Erika will ein Stativ *auf* dem Tisch *aufbauen.*
>   Erika *baut* ein Stativ *auf* dem Tisch *auf.*

Das ist, wie ich meine, völlig einwandfreies Deutsch.

<sub>Willi will sein Auto vor dem Hagel schützen:</sub>

> Willi hat sein Auto *untergestellt*.
>   Willi hat sein Auto *unter* das Flugdach *untergestellt*.
>   Willi will sein Auto *unter* das Flugdach *unterstellen*.
>   Willi *stellt* sein Auto *unter* das Flugdach *unter*.

Nach meinem Empfinden ist das schon ein klein wenig schräg, aber durchaus noch in Ordnung.

<sub>Vera war lange im finstern Keller und tritt nun ins Freie. Die grelle Sonne scheint ihr direkt ins Gesicht und blendet sie:</sub>

> Vera hat die Hand *vorgehalten*.
>   Vera hat die Hand *vor* die Augen *vorgehalten*.
>   Vera will die Hand *vor* die Augen *vorhalten*.
>   Vera *hält* die Hand *vor* die Augen *vor*.

Den letzen Satz halte ich zumindest stilistisch für eine Katastrophe.

**Warum ist *»eine Hand vorhalten«* anders als *»ein Stativ aufbauen«,* wenn doch die grammatischen Konstruktionen identisch sind?**

Comment: Auf den ersten Blick: Fortschreitender Grad von Idiomatisierung. Zum Beispiel ist "Erika baut ein Stativ auf dem Tisch auf." nicht mehr äquivalent zu "Erika baut ein Stativ auf dem Tisch." (im Gegensatz zu dem Kaffee-Beispiel).

Comment: Könnte auch Zufall sein, aber interessant finde ich auch, dass sich die Beispiele vom Gefühl mit Dativ her weniger schräg anfühlen als mit Akkusativ (Erika vs. Vera; und "Willi stellt sein Auto unter *dem* Flugdach unter." klingt meiner Meinung nach besser als "Willi stellt sein Auto unter *das* Flugdach unter.")

Comment: Ich denke, vieles erklärt sich aus der Ethymologie: Das trennbare Verb *unterhalten* dürfte ursprünglich aus der haüfig verwendeten Kombination der Präposition mit dem Verb entstanden sein. Außerhalb einer zusätzlichen Angabe, **wo** etwas geschieht (siehe @MartinRosenaus Antwort), ist die Verwendung des trennbaren Verbs + *nochmal* die Präposition zumindestens eine Art von Tautologie und damit, wenn man sie nicht für einen bestimmten Zweck einsetzt, stilistisch wohl nicht einwandfrei.

Answer (score 1):

Die grammatikalischen Konstruktionen sind ja nicht alles.

Meiner Meinung nach ist es der Sinn der Worte, der in allen Fällen unterschiedlich ist und den letzten Satz zumindest stilistisch unmöglich macht.

Nehmen wir das Beispiel mit dem "unterhalten":

> Im Garten sind zwei tropfende Wasserhähne: Einer unter dem Vordach und einer in der Laube. Ich halte **unter** dem Vordach einen Eimer **unter**.

In diesem Fall bezieht sich die Vorsilbe "unter-" des Verbs "unterhalten" auf den Wasserhahn und das Wort "unter" auf das Vordach - also auf zwei unterschiedliche Gegenstände.

Dasselbe ist beim "**Auf**bauen des Stativs **auf** dem Tisch" der Fall.

Wenn ich hingegen sage:

> Ich halte unter de**m** [Dativ] Wasserhahn einen Eimer unter.

... würde das meiner Meinung nach bedeuten, dass man den Eimer unter irgendetwas hält, was sich unter dem Wasserhahn befindet.

Wenn man anstatt des Dativs den Akkusativ verwendet, wüsste ich noch nicht einmal, was der Satz bedeuten würde ...